# Unable to load config.js

Tags: android, ios, flutter, jitsi

I am using the [Jitsi Flutter plugin](https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet) in conjunction with [8x8's Jitsi-as-a-Service offering](https://jaas.8x8.vc/) to integrate video calls into my mobile app.

Immediately after joining a meeting, the call ends and Jitsi closes. The logs indicate that the  underlying Jitsi Meet SDK is unable to fetch `config.js` from 8x8:

```
E/JitsiMeetSDK(10937): [features/base/lib-jitsi-meet] Failed to load config from https://8x8.vc/vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>/hello-world/config.js?room=vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>hello-world Error(Error){"message":"loadScript error: undefined","stack":"index.android.bundle:538:817\np@index.android.bundle:284:423\nindex.android.bundle:284:1740\np@index.android.bundle:284:423\nn@index.android.bundle:284:898\nindex.android.bundle:284:1047\nf@index.android.bundle:111:155\nindex.android.bundle:111:882\ny@index.android.bundle:117:661\nC@index.android.bundle:117:1025\ncallImmediates@index.android.bundle:117:3100\ncallImmediates@[native code]\nvalue@index.android.bundle:36:3247\nindex.android.bundle:36:1283\nvalue@index.android.bundle:36:2939\nvalue@index.android.bundle:36:1253\nvalue@[native code]\nvalue@[native code]"}
I/JitsiMeetSDK(10937): [features/overlay] The conference will be reloaded after 19 seconds.
D/JitsiMeetSDK(10937): ExternalAPI Sending event: CONFERENCE_TERMINATED with data: { NativeMap: {"url":"https://8x8.vc/vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>/hello-world/vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>hello-world","error":"Error: loadScript error: undefined"} }
E/ThemeUtils(10937): View class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
I/chatty  (10937): uid=10179(com.example.app) identical 1 line
E/ThemeUtils(10937): View class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
D/JITSI_MEET_PLUGIN(10937): JitsiMeetPluginActivity.onConferenceTerminated: {error=Error: loadScript error: undefined, url=https://8x8.vc/vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>/hello-world/vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>hello-world}
D/JITSI_MEET_PLUGIN(10937): JitsiMeetEventStreamHandler.onConferenceTerminated
I/JitsiMeetSDK(10937): Conference terminated: {error=Error: loadScript error: undefined, event=onConferenceTerminated, url=https://8x8.vc/vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>/hello-world/vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>hello-world}
I/JitsiMeetSDK(10937): [features/base/connection] No connection found while disconnecting.
```

I followed the [official 8x8 JaaS docs](https://developer.8x8.com/jaas/docs/mobile-sdk-overview) on how to configure Jitsi in my app:

```
_joinMeeting(String token, String userName) async {
    FeatureFlag featureFlag = FeatureFlag();
    featureFlag.welcomePageEnabled = false;
    // ...
    featureFlag.resolution = FeatureFlagVideoResolution.HD_RESOLUTION;

    var options = JitsiMeetingOptions()
      ..serverURL = "https://8x8.vc"
      ..room = "vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>/hello-world"
      ..subject = "Hello World"
      ..token = token
      ..userDisplayName = userName
      ..audioOnly = false
      ..audioMuted = true
      ..videoMuted = true
      ..featureFlag = featureFlag;

    await JitsiMeet.joinMeeting(options, roomNameConstraints: Map());
  }
```

It works flawlessly with the public `meet.jit.si` servers but does not with 8x8's JaaS offering. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using 8x8's JaaS offering with the Jitsi Flutter plugin

**TL;DR:** Set the full URL of your 8x8 meeting as the room name.

---

If you follow the [official 8x8 Jaas docs](https://developer.8x8.com/jaas/docs/mobile-sdk-overview), you will likely end up with Jitsi Flutter being unable to load `config.js` from the 8x8 server.

[This forum comment](https://community.jitsi.org/t/onboarding-improvement-merge-8x8-and-jitsi/95845/4) hints that one can join 8x8 meetings via the official Jitsi Meet app from the App Store by using the full 8x8 meeting URL as the room name.

As a matter of fact, this not only works for the official app, but also for the Jitsi Flutter plugin. Using the configuration below you should be able to connect to a meeting room on your 8x8 tenant. **Please make sure to disable any room name constraints by passing an empty map to `joinMeeting`, otherwise Jitsi Flutter will reject your room name!**

```
_joinMeeting(String token, String userName) async {
    FeatureFlag featureFlag = FeatureFlag();
    featureFlag.welcomePageEnabled = false;
    // ...
    featureFlag.resolution = FeatureFlagVideoResolution.HD_RESOLUTION;

    var options = JitsiMeetingOptions()
      ..serverURL = "https://8x8.vc"
      ..room = "https://8x8.vc/vpaas-magic-cookie-<tenantID>/<roomName>"
      ..subject = "Hello World"
      ..token = token
      ..userDisplayName = userName
      ..audioOnly = false
      ..audioMuted = true
      ..videoMuted = true
      ..featureFlag = featureFlag;

    await JitsiMeet.joinMeeting(options, roomNameConstraints: Map());
  }
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Failed to load config from -Jitsi Url- Error(TypeError)"message":"Network request failed" error by adding SSL not only to Flutter but also to native sides. Because the jitsi meet join function works by creating a bridge to the native side. The SSL you integrated into the project only covers Flutter. Good luck.